# Koa.js import x from 'y' not working

Tags: koa

I'm using PM2 to server my Koa backend. However when I use imports it serves no website / crashes. What's the work around for this? I see Koa snippets with imports all over. Node v7.6 stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a Koa-specific related issue. The ES6 `import/export` module syntax hasn't been implemented yet in browsers or node. For now, you can just use `const x = require('y')`. If you want to use the `import/export` syntax, you will need to use something like [`babel`](http://babeljs.io) which converts your next-gen JS code into code that can run.